# I am trying to run Project and getting error YII 2 ReflectionException Class yii\debug\Module does not exist

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am trying to run Yii2 advanced application and getting error,

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, do you have yii2 debug module in your composer.json file?

Comment: YES
"require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },

Comment: Do you have up to date composer.lock file? From the screen shot I can see that you have some trouble while doing composer update

Comment: composer.lock file is not up to date

Comment: I am trying but give me error

Comment: Yeap because you have issues which you need to fix, just read the errors :)